# Initial count on Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I just put a Like button up on my site and immediately  the count is 25.  What does this mean, since I'm sure 25 people haven't Liked the site already.  Can I change this value?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: aren't there 25 comments on your site already by chance? http://almightylink.ksablan.com/statistics/facebook-button-count-is-wrong-use-realshare/

Answer (score 1):

The [Like Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) says:

> **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> - The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

As far as I know, you cannot change the number manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. You **can't** change the count
2. Make sure that the `href` is empty (if XFBML) or set to your page
3. Try running your link on the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Answer (score 0):

As your app link: `https://myapp.com` shared in user profiles, facebook groups, facebook pages, your `like`  count increments. Event it is deleted, as an example, facebook page owner doesn't want ad of your app, your `like` count doesn't decrement.

In your case as you have your domain, and as it is already mentioned above places, you've 25 `like`s.

Comment: So if I understand this, there are already 25 references to my site somewhere in Facebook?  Is there anyway to see them?  And how do we know they're "Likes"?  25 people may be complaining about the site! Wouldn't that bump the counter?

Thanks